# Sort by first digits of a number column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE client_details(
   ...
   clientid number(10,0) ,
   name varchar2,
   ...
)
```

Where `clientid` could be some unique number (external id from another source).

I need to implement filtering by `clientd`, so a system will display all records where `clientid` *begins with* user-inputed value

For example:

let the table contains the following data:

```
[{clientId=119, name='Bob'},
 {clientId=11234,name='Anna'},
 {clientId=2,name='Eva'}]
```

When a user inputs "11" as a search query, then the system will show:

```
[{clientId=119, name='Bob'},
 {clientId=11234,name='Anna'}]
```

When a user inputs "2" as a search query, then the system will show:

```
 [{clientId=2, name='Eva'}]
```

A user can input any number from 0 to 999999999 as a query.

My original intention is to use something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM client_details
WHERE SUBSTR(client, 0, length_of_query) = 'query'
```

(where query stands for user input and length_of_query stands for query lengths as a string)

I a bit dislike substr and converting int to string in where, s.a. the table could be quite big. On the other hand I would prefer not to change DB structure.

Maybe someone has a better idea?

Comment: I think the method you dislike is the one that work the best.

Comment: I also dislike `substr` as it's only possible to create a function based index on a fixed length `substr` of the original column -- a `substr` expression using a different lenght won't use that index.

Comment: If it's valid to assign some meaning to the first digit of a number, then what you have there is not a number but a string for which the only legal characters are digits. You should probably reconsider storing this in a number datatype.

Comment: My bad, sorry for confusing example. It is not just the first digit, it could be several of them. For example user could input 179 that means 'retrieve all records with clientid starts with 179' for example 1790, 179, 179237884

Answer (score 3):

Cast to a string and use the `like` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM client_details
WHERE TO_CHAR(clientId) LIKE <<query>> || '%'
```

Create an index on `client_details(TO_CHAR(clientId))` and you'll get great performance too when the users type more than a few numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Perform **CONVERSION** *using(CAST or CONVERT)* and use **LIKE** operator but Do read [these](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/) [Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) before changing datatype.

```
SELECT *  
FROM [Clients_details]  
WHERE CAST(clientId AS Varchar(50)) LIKE 'query%';
```